# EntityType for a ManyToMany relation

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many, symfony-forms

I have a relation of Many-To-Many between my two entities Ad and City, now I'm working on the *AdType* form, and I get this error after submitting it:

> ````
> Could not determine access type for property "cities" in class "App\Entity\Ad": The property "cities" in class "App\Entity\Ad" can be defined with the methods "addCity()", "removeCity()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "App\Entity\City" given... ```
> ````

If I have to use `CollectionType` I need to be able to load my choices from the database, and I need to have just one city selected.

AdType.php

```php
->add('cities',
    EntityType::class,
    $this->getConfiguration(
        "Ville",
        "Sélectionnez votre ville",
        [
            'class' => 'App\Entity\City',
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ]
    )
)
```

Ad.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\City", inversedBy="ads")
 */
private $cities;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and let me know if it is work because once i had the same probleme:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
          ->add('cities', EntityType::class, array(
            'label' => false,
            'class' => 'App\Entity\city',
            'required'=>true,
            'expanded'=>true,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('v')
                    ->orderBy('v.nomDeLaville', 'ASC');
            },
            "choice_label" => "Sélectionnez votre ville",
            'multiple' => false,
            'label_attr' => array(
                'class' => '')))
        ;
    }
```

Comment: this would allow to select multiple choices which is not what i want really, i'm trying to use the CollectionType with 'entry_type' => ChoiceType::class but i need the choices to load from the database.

Comment: i just modified my answer try it and let me know: this code allows you to load all list of your city from database by their names. @ouassim